# Region won't show on front-page

Tags: theming

I'm customizing a theme and need to have a leaderboard on top of the page. Everything good - on all pages but not the home (front-page)... Any ideas what I did wrong?

I've added a region to the .info file

```
regions[topad] = Leaderboard header
```

and printed that region to the page.tpl.php like that:

```
 <?php if ($page ['topad']): ?>
   <div id="topad">
        <?php print render($page['topad']); ?>
   </div> <!-- /#topad -->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I added a block with the leaderboard infos to the region and told it to show up on every page (also tried specific pages with "" - didn't work).

I'm happy for every hint.

Thank you!

Best

Chris

Comment: Try removing the space in your if statement. $page['topad'] instead of $page ['topad'].

Comment: Thank you. I did that but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Is you page.tpl.php actually labeled page-tpl.php using a hyphen instead of a period?

Just for posterity, you might want to update the typos in your question as well, because those little things do make a difference.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that. It's the page.tpl.php - I've edited it.

Comment: Have you tried making just a static block with a title and text and putting it on all pages, testing it in one region and another to see if it shows up everywhere else?

Comment: Hi Kyle, first of all thank you for your help! Yes, I did that and the block shows up in every region and every page, just not on front-page. It seems that the region is not showing up on the front-page. So there must be something defining the "front-page". The front-page is a basic page defined as front-page on confg/system/site information. Could it be that regions of the element "front-page" are defined somewhere else?

Comment: So for a region to render, there must be something inside it that is being rendered or it won't show up. And when you say front page, you don't mean like some kind of specific template, right? Also try using <front> for the front page path when setting the block on a path.

Comment: Try to `dpm($page)` and see if `$page['topad']` is set

Comment: Thank you! Probelm solved as the front-page was rendered by a different template within a strange labelled subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a specific template for your front page?  Is your front page pointing at a node?  Or just a list of recent updates?

Comment: No specific template. Home is a basic page with name "home", set as front page within config/system/site information.

Comment: are you willing/able to install the Devel and "Theme Developer" modules?  https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer

You can use it to see exactly which template is being used. I'm convinced that your front page is not using the standard page template.  also, are you sure you've got your block set up in terms of "Show block on specific pages" ?

Comment: Hi JDU, that solved the problem! The front-page had a specific template within a strangely labelled subfolder. Inserting the code there solved the problem. Thank you!